# creating punctuation free lists?

Tags: python, jinja2

Normally you define list in jinja like this :

```
{% set lst = ['abc','def','egh', .... ] %}
```

Is there a way to write plain text inside the template and then parse it somehow into list. f.e.:

```
{% set lst <= abc def egh ....%}
```

also allow it to be multi-line.

the reason is that i need to write many big lists inside the templates

Comment: You could load those lists from a file(s) so you don't have to write them manually into the template.

Comment: the reason is every list has to be close to the block it is used ... splitting in files makes it harder to manage.. and is easier to make mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, you can use `split` method of the strings directly from the jinja2 template. Like this:

```
{% set text %}abc def jhi{% endset %}
{% set strings=text.split(' ') %}
>> {{ strings }} <<
```

will give you:

```
>> ['abc', 'def', 'jhi'] <<
```

In this sample `strings` variable contains array of strings splitted by the space. In this sample original string splitted by the new line:

```
{% set text -%}
abc
def
jhi
{%- endset %}
{% set strings=text.split('\n') %}
>> {{ strings }} <<
```

With the same result. You can use other string functions like `partition`, `rsplit` etc. as well.

Comment: this does not seem to work : {% xdict = { 'lst' : strings } %}, do i have to do something special .. it is there but doesnt loop over it !!

Comment: i got confused because of the dict order , too many entries and i didnt see it... everything is ok..thanks